# How to create Web API using MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with .Net Framework 4 and ASP.NET MVC 3.

I want to make my controller method available to external applications like (Web sites, mobile apps, etc.) as a Web API. I tried finding the solution on web, however got all links pointing to "Web API2 Controllers" with VS 2013 e.g. [this one](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). It is not possible for me to upgrade Visual Studio and .net framework at this stage.

Is there any way I can achieve this using .NET 4 and ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: WebAPI is not implemented using MVC, it's a separate framework, although it does ship with MVC4.  You can upgrade to MVC4 with Visual Studio 2010, and use WebApi as well.

Comment: @Mystere Man - If that is the case, then is this what I need? Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi?

Comment: What you referring to specifically?  That's just a namespace.

Comment: I found one link on web, saying we can use Nuget package for WebApi to achieve this using .net 4

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  However, I would not do so using MVC3, I would upgrade to MVC4 which was designed to work with WebApi.  It may work with MVC3, but there may be problems you run into.

Comment: I tried to install it and got this error: "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to install the latest version of WebAPI, and not the older version.  You need to use the command line nuget tools and specify the version number

Answer (score 12):

To get Web API in MVC3 project, please do following changes -

**Step 1** - Create MVC3 Project with .Net 4.

**Step 2** - Install Web API using Package Manager - **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 4.0.30506**

**Step 3** - Add following route in Global.asax with referencing `using System.Web.Http;` -

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Step 4** - Create a controller -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        public string Get()
        {
            return "1";
        }

    }
}
```

**Step 5** - Execute the project and go to the url - **/api/values**. Thats it, we got our Web API running.

Comment: After installing the package successfully, I don't get either System.Web.Http or ApiController in the code. I mean, it gives syntax error on these words after typing in.

Comment: Can you see if those references were added successfully or not? Also try it out this way, create a blank MVC project and give a try. Between I tried it in VS 2012 and it worked for me seamlessly.

Comment: No luck with new MVC project as well.

Comment: Are you sure, package got installed without any errors? Check the console to see if there are any errors and post them back.

Answer (score 2):

There is no WebAPI for MVC 3. Upgrade to MVC 4 or use ServiceStack to implement RESTful layer

https://servicestack.net/

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/